# How I can create the simple java project?

Tags: intellij-idea, jetbrains-ide

Why I cann't create the simple java project? I have only Groovy module.
[image: module window]

Comment: @Santa thanks. It isn`t friendly user interface :(

Comment: How is that not a user-friendly interface? Java is selected and the Next button is highlighted, what more do you want?

Comment: @Michael when I see Groovy at the right, I expect that, as in the case with Android is its submenu

Comment: @nanotexnik that is just offering to add additional libraries to the project. That list will be quite large the more plugins you have. Have you uninstalled some of the bundled plugins?

Comment: @Michael, I don`t uninstall pligins

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
File -> New project -> java -> then without clicking nethng just next ->
next->Type nameOfProject ->Finish
```